# conditional concatenation in expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am binding a list box using ng-repeat.

```
<option ng-repeat="o in Carrier value="{{o.CarrierKey}}"> {{o.CarrierName}} | {{o.PolicyNumber}}</option>
```

How do i use a conditional concationation in above code. I want last pipe and policy number to be displayed only when PolicyNumber is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a ternary and doing concatenation, just use a span with `ng-if` like:

```html
<option ng-repeat="o in Carrier value={{o.CarrierKey}}">{{o.CarrierName}}
  <span ng-if="o.PolicyNumber">| {{o.PolicyNumber}}</span>
</option>
```

ternary would be something like `{{o.PolicyNumber? '| ' + o.PolicyNumber : ''}}`